# Как передать информацию в аннотацию?

Tags: java, generics, аннотации

Использую кастомную аннотацию `@Example("objectName")`, которая переносит нужную информацию - `"objectName"`. Задался спортивным вопросом - как в аннотацию передать информацию? Попробовал использовать Generic для такого кейса:

```
    public class GenericObject<T> {

    @Example(T) 
    Object data;
    }
```

Или например что-то вроде:

```
    public class GenericObject<T> {

    @Example(T.toString()) 
    Object data;
    }
```

Увы для Generic допустимо использовать только классы-обёртки типа Integer.

Вопрос в том, что какие есть способы создать класс с динамически генерируемой аннотацией?

Comment: Это очень сумбурный вопрос, с ужасной путаницей в терминах и определениях. Строка "objectName" - это информация, так что вы уже знаете, как в аннотацию передать информацию. Что может означать запись вида `@аннотация(тип)` я даже предположить не могу. А уж тем более не понять, чего вы ждёте от `тип.toString()`. Словосочетание же "динамически генерируемой аннотацией" вовсе не вяжется с обобщёнными типами, так как последние существуют только до этапа компиляции и являются предельно статичными.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev Спасибо, очень полезно почитать как вы умничаете. Если вы не в состоянии понять суть вопроса, так отчего бы не пройти мимо? Это всегда хорошая идея по сравнению с тем, чтобы тыкать на некорректное использование терминов вместо ответа на вопрос.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev А вы не слышали, что бывают аннотации типа @Annotation("text)? За примером далеко ходить не надо, в JPA существует аннотация OrderBy с параметром: OrderBy("firstName asc").

Comment: Боюсь, что если я или кто-то другой не сможем уточнить, что именно вы имеете ввиду, то вы не сможете получить ответ. Мой комментарий обоснован только этим и в нём не было попытки вас оскорбить.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev Суть вопроса такова: можно ли в аннотацию поместить информацию не только на этапе описания класса? Что после компиляции класс становится статичным прекрасно известно. Поясню - кастомные аннотации на этом проекте используются для хранения в них имён, соответствующих этим полям в Oracle базе. Это, мне кажется, изящно. Бывает необходимость передать в хранимую процедуру только один параметр. И тогда возникает необходимость писать отдельный класс только для этой процедуры. Вот я и стал искать способ написать один класс, но параметр, содержащийся в аннотации, менять динамически.

Comment: `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)` вам в помощь.

Comment: @Suvitruf Оставьте, пожалуйста, это как ответ, для того, чтобы я мог принять его.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объявим аннотацию:

```
@Retention (RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    String name() default "";
}
```

Реализуем в классе:

```
public static class DynamicAnnotation implements MyAnnotation {
    private String name;

    public DynamicAnnotation(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String name() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
        return DynamicAnnotation.class;
    }
}

@MyAnnotation(name = "Dragon Warrior")
public static class Demo {
}
```

Метод по замене:

```
private static final String ANNOTATIONS = "annotations";
public static final String ANNOTATION_DATA = "annotationData";

public static void alterAnnotationOn(Class clazzToLookFor, Class<? extends Annotation> annotationToAlter, Annotation annotationValue) {
    try {
        Method method = Class.class.getDeclaredMethod(ANNOTATION_DATA, null);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        Object annotationData = method.invoke(clazzToLookFor);
        Field annotations = annotationData.getClass().getDeclaredField(ANNOTATIONS);
        annotations.setAccessible(true);
        Map<Class<? extends Annotation>, Annotation> map = (Map<Class<? extends Annotation>, Annotation>) annotations.get(annotationData);
        map.put(annotationToAlter, annotationValue);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Проверяем:

```
MyAnnotation greet = Demo.class.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
System.err.println("Hello there [" + greet.name() + "]");
DynamicAnnotation altered = new DynamicAnnotation("KungFu Panda");
alterAnnotationOn(Demo.class, MyAnnotation.class, altered);
greet = Demo.class.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
System.err.println("After alteration...Hello there [" + greet.name() + "]");
```

Выведет:

```
Hello there [Dragon Warrior]
After alteration...Hello there [KungFu Panda]
```

Пример [отсюда](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2016/05/27/changing-annotation-values-at-runtime/). Я скопировал только пример для Java 8. Там есть и для Java 7.